# calling function to be used on windows form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

this is in my OfficeEquipment.Frm

```
Public Function Loadfunction()
dt = Functions.LoadData()
End Function
```

and this is the error for the above code

Warning 1   Function 'Loadfunction' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.   C:\Documents and Settings\IJDinglasan\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Electronic Office Equipment History\Electronic Office Equipment History\Update Office Equipment Profile.vb   9   5   Electronic Office Equipment History

this is in my module Functions

```
Private Function LoadData() As DataTable

Using sqlconn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
                                             "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true")
Dim dt As New DataTable
sqlconn.Open()
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentProfile", sqlconn)
da.Fill(dt)
Return dt
End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically just use the class and the function you have....

```
 Dim dt As DataTable
 dt = yourclass.LoadData()
```

Now dt is your table that you can use where you like.

MrCoDeXeR

EDITS

Where ever you have your function (LoadData) you need to reference that class and the function. For example: say my main class is: frmMain.vb and my class that has my function is: frmStudents I want to get that function.

So.... on frmMain.vb you need to declare another DataTable and assign it.... see below...

```
 Dim dt As DataTable
 dt = frmStudents.LoadData()
```

We call the function from frmStudents and fill our new table with our data. What you need to do is set a breakpoint on: dt = frmStudents.LoadData() and run your solution. When you get to that line press F-11 and see if it jumps over to you other class that has your function. then press F-11 and continue to step-through and see if it throws an error. On your: Return dt in your function, hover over this if it makes it this far and click the magnifying glass and see if data exists or has your column names, if so your good to go...

Comment: sir yourclass is the class1.vb?

Comment: Yes whatever class holds your function.

Comment: i named it functions making it

dim dt as datatable
dt = functions.loadData but doesnt work

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on your function and step through, your issue is there.

Comment: Also after you LoadData make sure you close it off with parentheses ().

Comment: Public Function LoadData()

        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = Functions.LoadData()
    End Function

blue underlign beneath functions.loaddata sir

Comment: Is this function inside the class you are calling it from?

Comment: thank you for the sir, marked it as answered, but ill still be trying to figure it out still not working new to vb

Comment: As I have mentioned just step through you code on your function... your issue lays there. Im not sure because I dont' have you data or anything else so it's hard to really tell where its happening at, but rest assure its in that function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29514/discussion-between-ivandinglasan-and-mr-codexer)